# limit of $(\frac{x^{2}+3x}{x^{2}+2x+3})^{2x\cdot\lfloor x \rfloor} $ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to compute the limit of $(\frac{x^{2}+3x}{x^{2}+2x+3})^{2x\cdot\lfloor x \rfloor}$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$ and I'm stuck on what to do with the floor function in the exponent. Any tips/hints would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: My first thought is to try to use: $ x-1\leq \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$

Answer (score 0):

The limit is infinity. Sketch:

$\frac{x^{2}+3x}{x^{2}+2x+3}\le 1$ if $x\ge 1$ so  $(\frac{x^{2}+3x}{x^{2}+2x+3})^{2x^2}\le (\frac{x^{2}+3x}{x^{2}+2x+3})^{2x\cdot\lfloor x \rfloor}.$

Now, it's easy to show directly (L'Hospital, for example), that the
left-hand side of this inequality is unbounded as $x\to \infty.$

Or note that $\left(\frac{x^{2}+3x}{x^{2}+2x+3}\right)^x\to e$ as $x\to \infty$ so there is an $M>0$ such that $x>M\Rightarrow \left(\frac{x^{2}+3x}{x^{2}+2x+3}\right)^x>2$. It follows that  $2^{2x}\le (\frac{x^{2}+3x}{x^{2}+2x+3})^{2x\cdot\lfloor x \rfloor}$ as soon as $x>M.$